# Python script closes automatically after few seconds when it performs object detection on RTSP live feed from IP camera?

Tags: python, image-processing, rtsp

I am doing image processing on RTSP link. When I just capture live feed from RTSP and just shows in python then it works fine and perfectly. But When I implement object detection on that RTSP live feed from ip camera then it works fine for few seconds. Objects are detected for few seconds but after that my python script automatically closes. Python script reaches at the last line of the code and then stops.I do not want to close the script automatically after few seconds.

Comment: Please share what code you have.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret==True:
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)),0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
              confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
              if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                       idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
                       box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
                       (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
                       label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx],confidence * 100)
                       cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),COLORS[idx], 2)
                       y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
                       cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)
                       if idx==15:
                           out.write(frame)
                           print("This is person")
                       else:
                           break
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
else:
    break
```